# How to find the length of two points on the same image

Tags: opencv, image-processing, contour

I just wanted to find the length in between two points on the same image using open cv. Can someone help me to get through this?

What I've done so far: Got the contour of the image using this code sample.

```
for cnt in contours:
    epsilon = 0.01* cv2.arcLength(cnt,True)
    approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(cnt,epsilon,True)
    img = cv2.drawContours(img, [approx], 0, (0,255,0), 3)
```

Measurement which I exactly need - Lenght of the shoulder size which I have drawn using Red straight line in RED color. Is there any way to detect those two points and find the length of the shoulders.

Expected : To find the length of the RED line

[image]

Comment: You are asking how to find the length of the red line, however I presume somehow that the red line was drawn just to explain what you need, and would not be present on the images you analyze. Please [edit] your question to clarify it. What information do you have? How do you define these two points? Do you have the green detection as a polygon? Can these points be defined as two points on the polygon?

Comment: @ Cris Luengo I've edited the question! Please check.! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score -1):

Given 2 points in a 2D image A and B with pixel coordinates (xA, yA) and (xB, yB) respectively (x for column number, y for row number).

The distance between them is obtained by:

[image: formula distance 2 points]

Here's the documentation for approxPolyDP:
https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.0/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#ga0012a5fdaea70b8a9970165d98722b4c

From the docs you might notice that the output of this function is an array of points (in the order as they are connected).

If you still haven't found which points of your contour are the shoulders, you can just look for the highest points and use a threshold (top of the head), then jump 2 more points away. You can easily figure out a more robust method.

Comment: Hi. I'm really new to this topic. Can you just explain me how to exactly get the pixel coordinates for the shoulder points only?

Comment: You've got the array of points so all you need to do is find the shoulder points and apply the formula. If you have basic Python understanding you should be able to figure it out.

Comment: You are glancing over the least trivial part. Finding the shoulder points is a hard problem. For one case, yes, you can hard-code that. But to make it work in a general case?

Comment: Yeah, since the OP said he's just starting I wanted him to get basic results before going deeper. The way you would do this in this era is to train a deep learning library to do pose estimation, which means you train it to figure out shoulders (as well as heads etc.). I would recommend trying https://github.com/CMU-Perceptual-Computing-Lab/openpose to get the labeled keypoints.

Comment: Cris Luengo I'm answering the question, not suggesting a computer vision method the OP hasn't asked for. There's a chance this is not a PhD researcher looking to do pose estimation but a simple student that doesn't know how to do Python array traversal.